# Unable to Link Glue and Feature File

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, testng

I am new to Cucumber and practicing it. I just created a simple project and try to compile it.I have mentioned the feature path and glue path in cucumber. But still whenever I am compiling with Junit keeps showing test is skipped Undefined scenarios.

```
TestRunner     


 package runner;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
    import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;


    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/test/resources/feature/feature.feature"
            ,glue = {"src/test/java/stepDefinition"} //have tried with "/HomeWork/src/test/java/stepDefinition/" also. but not working. giving error message like undefined scenarios
            ,monochrome = true
            ,plugin = {"html:target/Report/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/Report/cucumber-json-report.json" }
    )
    public class TestRunner {

    }



    stepDefinition File: 



package stepDefinition;

    import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
    import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

    public class firstLogin {
        WebDriver driver;



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        @Given("^User sets the property^")
        public void User_sets_the_property() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver. chrome.driver",
                    "C:\\Arnab\\Softwares\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application");

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        }

        @When("^User navigates to login page^")
        public void User_navigates_to_login_page() {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=émail']")).sendKeys(
                    "arnab.test1115@gail.com");
            driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//input[@class='inputtext login_form_input_box']"))
                    .sendKeys("mandira1990");
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Log In']")).click();
        }

        @Then("user is on Homepage^")
        public void user_is_on_Homepage() throws InterruptedException {
            String Title = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println(Title);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }


        // driver.close();

    }
```

Feature File:

```
 Feature: User is on Facebook Login Page

    Scenario: User Needs to Login

    Given User sets the property

    When User navigates to login page

    Then user is on Homepage
```

Comment: Glue should be a package name. So `glue={"stepDefinition"}`.

Comment: I have tried by giving glue={"stepDefinition"} only. But same error coming

Comment: Worth going through the tutorial then https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The parameter values you have provided in `@CucumberOptions` may not be configured correctly as required by Cucumber.

`features` is for a filesystem folder path of where a feature file can be found and not the full file path.

`glue` is the package name of where your step definition class is, not the filesystem path to the package itself.

So your configuration should be like this:

```
    @CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/feature"
        ,glue = {"stepDefinition"} 
        ,monochrome = true
        ,plugin = {"html:target/Report/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/Report/cucumber-json-report.json" }
)
```